# Urxvt - powerline wrong color

Tags: zsh, rxvt, powerline

after quite a hard time I actually get powerline work in urxvt.
There is only one problem left:

http://i57.tinypic.com/nnk4g9.png

Does sombody know how I switch the bg-color of the command-number?
It's impossible for me to set the color correctly...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it:

There is a option to set colors for each element in powerline oh-my-zsh-theme:

```
POWERLEVEL_HISTORY_BACKGROUND = "black"
```